# Trying to get array defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the following error:

```
angular.min.js:114TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined at templateController.js:28
```

It's because of this line of code:

```
$scope.filteredTemplates = $scope.templates.slice(begin, end);
```

And here is my code:

```
var template = angular.module('TemplateCtrl',['ui.bootstrap']);

template.controller('TemplateController',function($scope, Template){
    var getTemplates = Template.all();
    $scope.filteredTemplates = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 10;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    getTemplates.success(function(response){
        if(response[0] == 200){   
            $scope.templates = response[1];

        }else{
           //user wasn't logged in to view the templates (voorbeeld contracten)
            console.log('Please log in');
        }
    });

    $scope.numPages = function () {
        return Math.ceil($scope.templates.length / $scope.numPerPage);
      };

    $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.filteredTemplates = $scope.templates.slice(begin, end);
      });
});
```

I'm trying to make a pagination for my array in `$scope.templates`.

Therefore I'm using the `$watch()` method to see on which page the user is. And to slice the array in `$scope.templates` depending on which page the user has clicked on.

However I'm using a callback as you see in the `.success()` method. And the problem with a callback is that you don't know when it gets executed.

Because of that the `$watch()` gets executed first and sees ofcourse that `$scope.templates` is undefined.. Gladly I want to ask if someone knows how I can still make this pagination work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your watch is getting executed before the getTemplates getting resolved. So you don't have $scope.templates. Define $scope.template = []; up top and execute slice only if $scope.template.length>0

```
 $scope.templates = [];
 $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    if($scope.templates.length>0){
        $scope.filteredTemplates = $scope.templates.slice(begin, end);
    }
  });
```